# Bounded function $x(t)$ such that $x''(t) - 4x(t) = \cos(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all bounded function $x(t)$ such that $x''(t) - 4x(t) = \cos(t)$.

This is quite easy differential equation. We have $x(t) = C_1 e^{2t} + C_2 e^{-2t} - 
\frac{1}{5} \cos(t)$. But when it is bounded? I suppose that for $C_1=C_2=0$ so we have only one bounded solution and it is $x(t)= - \frac{1}{5} \cos(t)$.

I don't have answer for this task so i will grateful if you could check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asked for bounded solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ then the only solution is indeed $-\frac{1}{5} \cos t$. For instance, if $C_1 > 0$ then $x(t)=e^{2t} (C_1+C_2e^{-4t}-\frac{1}{5}e^{-2t} \cos t) \to +\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. You can [check its validity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5Bx%27%27%5Bt%5D%20-%204%20x%5Bt%5D%20==%20Cos%5Bt%5D,%20x%5Bt%5D,%20t%5D) by computational engine Wolfram Alpha